# Pagination not working - Datatables 1.10.9

Tags: ajax, server-side, datatables-1.10

I am using server side processing (AJAX requests) to get my table with data. I am getting the correct data. However, pagination is not working. The table info on the bottom left says Showing 1 to 10 of 182 entries and the bottom right shows the page numbers as well but the table shows all the possible records in the first page itself. Here's the code I use:

```
$(tableId).DataTable({
"paging": true,
"scrollX": true,
"filter": false,
"serverSide":true,
"columns": [
{"data":'transaction_id'},
{"data":'merchant_id'},
{"data":'merchant_provider_id'},
{"data":'transaction_uuid'},
{"data":'transaction_status_type'},
{"data":'transaction_payment_method'},
{"data":'transaction_amount'},
{"data":'transaction_amount_aud'},
{"data":'transaction_aud_exchange_rate'},
{"data":'transaction_amount_usd'},
{"data":'transaction_usd_exchange_rate'},
{"data":'transaction_currency'},
{"data":'transaction_created'},
{"data":'transaction_processed'},
{"data":'transaction_settled'},
],
"ajax": {
"url": requestUrl,
"data": values
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using server side processing with Datatables, the server side handles dividing the entries into pages. The ajax request will include parameters for offset (start) and page length (length). The server side must use these parameters to select and return the correct entries for each page.

Comment: Thank you your reply. So i need to pass iDisplaylength: 10 as a parameter in my AJAX request right?

Comment: So I tried adding the parameter "iDisplayLength" to my datatables initialization and AJAX request. But, my table still shows all the rows of data in the first page itself.

Comment: First, I apologize, iDisplayStart and iDisplayLength are the legacy parameters and I see you are using Datatables 1.10. These parameters are now just called "start" and "length". I have edited my answer to reflect this. Second, these parameters are already sent by Datables in the AJAX request. The program that handles the request will need to look at these parameters and limit the number of entries returned. In server side processing mode, Datatables will just display whatever records are returned by the AJAX request. The server must return the correct records for the given start and length.